# How we can avoid to write js code in views in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, partial-views

Hi i want to learn about very good practices about Rails conventions that we should put all

our JS code not in views rather then we put all js code in js files.

But when we working with nested level partials listed below and we need to refresh partials with ajax call or form submit with ajax then we some time need to put js code in our views.

```
        <div class="temp" ><%=render :partial => "question/list"%>          
           <div class="ans" ><%=render :partial => "answers/list"%></div>
        </div>
```

So what is the most best practices here.or we should write js code if needed.

Refer any tutorials or books.

Many many thanks

Comment: In rails 3 you can write js code in js.erb file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .js.erb file you can

`$("#temp").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'question/list') %>")`

and so on

Comment: Yes you are write but how i can do this when i use jquery ajax calls rather then unobtrusive js like remote => true.

Comment: when you fire ajax request use data type is script so  it will render .js.erb or if you don't want .js.erb then in response you will simply render partial in format.js block and on ajax success callback you will replace html.